# Window.Current in a WinJS application

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

I have a Window Runtime Component that accesses the Window.Current object, to add an handler on the VisibilityChanged event.

If I run that code in a C# Windows Store App, it runs perfectly (as soon as I do that in a method where the Window has been initialized).

Unfortunately, I am unable to do that in a WinJS app. It breaks when I launch the app.

Why ?

Thanks !

Comment: Where does it break? What exactly is the problem? Or, you are looking for an alternative for Window.Current in WinJS app?

Comment: The Window.Current object doesn't exist (just a null) when the window runtime component is executed within a WinJS app. Which is not the case when executed in a C# app. But I need to know if the app is visible, whatever its type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window.Current is a XAML concept. It simply doesn't exist in an HTML/JS app. You can't host or use XAML objects in a WinJS app.

You need to attach to the corresponding browser events instead, in Javascript.

Comment: But the code that uses the Window.Current is in a window runtime component, that will be shared between a C# and WinJS apps.

Comment: What WinRT type does Window.Current return?

Comment: @ChrisTavares is correct. You have to find a JavaScript equivalent.  [See this link]( http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/077eea6b-c24d-4745-ac1a-72b87e6c49a9)

Comment: This is what I have done. Not the best implementation nevertheless.